# ORA-06550 wrong number or types of arguments in call to Procedure, Statement ignored

Tags: c#, oracle

I am trying to insert data in to oracle database using Packaged stored procedure, But its giving the exception that wrong number or types of argument in call. Below is c# Code block

```
_unitOfWork.BeginTransaction();
                var ID = new OracleParameter("i_ID", OracleDbType.Decimal, null, ParameterDirection.InputOutput);
                var para = new OracleParameter[] {
                    ID,
                    new OracleParameter("i_PERSON_ID", OracleDbType.Decimal, iCPREC.PERSON_ID, ParameterDirection.Input),
                    new OracleParameter("i_VENDOR_NAME", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, iCPREC.VENDOR_NAME, ParameterDirection.Input),
                    new OracleParameter("i_BUSINESS_ID", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, iCPREC.BUSINESS_ID, ParameterDirection.Input),
                    new OracleParameter("i_MODIFIEDBY", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, iCPREC.MODIFIEDBY, ParameterDirection.Input),
                    new OracleParameter("i_VENDOR_PROVINCE", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, iCPREC.VENDOR_PROVINCE, ParameterDirection.Input),

                    new OracleParameter("i_GST_HST_NUMBER", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, iCPREC.GST_HST_NUMBER, ParameterDirection.Input),
                    new OracleParameter("i_VENDOR_SUITE", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, iCPREC.VENDOR_SUITE, ParameterDirection.Input),

                    new OracleParameter("i_PSF_SUPPLIER_ID", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, iCPREC.PSF_SUPPLIER_ID, ParameterDirection.Input),
                    new OracleParameter("i_TAX_EXEMPT", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, iCPREC.TAX_EXEMPT, ParameterDirection.Input),
                    new OracleParameter("i_DATEMODIFIED", OracleDbType.Date, iCPREC.DATEMODIFIED, ParameterDirection.Input),
                    new OracleParameter("i_VENDOR_STREET", OracleDbType.Varchar2, iCPREC.VENDOR_STREET, ParameterDirection.Input),
                    new OracleParameter("i_SK_PST_NUMBER", OracleDbType.Varchar2, iCPREC.SK_PST_NUMBER, ParameterDirection.Input),
                    new OracleParameter("i_QST_NUMBER", OracleDbType.Varchar2, iCPREC.QST_NUMBER, ParameterDirection.Input),
                    new OracleParameter("i_CREATEDBY", OracleDbType.Varchar2, iCPREC.CREATEDBY, ParameterDirection.Input),
                    new OracleParameter("i_VENDOR_POSTALCODE", OracleDbType.Varchar2, iCPREC.VENDOR_POSTALCODE, ParameterDirection.Input),
                    new OracleParameter("i_DATECREATED", OracleDbType.Date, iCPREC.DATECREATED, ParameterDirection.Input),
                    new OracleParameter("i_PERSON_EMAIL", OracleDbType.Varchar2, iCPREC.PERSON_EMAIL, ParameterDirection.Input),
                    new OracleParameter("i_VENDOR_CITY", OracleDbType.Varchar2, iCPREC.VENDOR_CITY, ParameterDirection.Input),
                };
                
                
                var result = await _unitOfWork.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("TAPK_ICPREC_DATA.tapp_main_insert", para);
```

Below is Oracle package sql package script

```
create or replace PACKAGE         TAPK_ICPREC_DATA IS  PROCEDURE tapp_main_insert(
  i_ID IN OUT number,
  i_VENDOR_NAME IN varchar2,
  i_BUSINESS_ID IN varchar2,
  i_MODIFIEDBY IN varchar2,
  i_VENDOR_PROVINCE IN varchar2,
  i_GST_HST_NUMBER IN varchar2,
  i_VENDOR_SUITE IN varchar2,
  i_PSF_SUPPLIER_ID IN varchar2,
  i_TAX_EXEMPT IN varchar2,
  i_DATEMODIFIED IN date,
  i_PERSON_ID IN number,
  i_VENDOR_STREET IN varchar2,
  i_SK_PST_NUMBER IN varchar2,
  i_QST_NUMBER IN varchar2,
  i_CREATEDBY IN varchar2,
  i_VENDOR_POSTALCODE IN varchar2,
  i_DATECREATED IN date,
  i_PERSON_EMAIL IN varchar2,
  i_VENDOR_CITY IN varchar2
);
END TAPK_ICPREC_DATA;
```

Below is Package Body Script

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY TAPK_ICPREC_DATA AS 

  PROCEDURE tapp_main_insert
     (
      i_ID                IN OUT number,
      i_VENDOR_NAME       IN varchar2,
      i_BUSINESS_ID       IN varchar2,
      i_MODIFIEDBY        IN varchar2,
      i_VENDOR_PROVINCE   IN varchar2,
      i_GST_HST_NUMBER    IN varchar2,
      i_VENDOR_SUITE      IN varchar2,
      i_PSF_SUPPLIER_ID   IN varchar2,
      i_TAX_EXEMPT        IN varchar2,
      i_DATEMODIFIED      IN date,
      i_PERSON_ID          IN number,
      i_VENDOR_STREET      IN varchar2,
      i_SK_PST_NUMBER      IN varchar2,
      i_QST_NUMBER      IN varchar2,
      i_CREATEDBY            IN varchar2,
      i_VENDOR_POSTALCODE     IN varchar2,
      i_DATECREATED            IN date,
      i_PERSON_EMAIL      IN varchar2 ,
      i_VENDOR_CITY    IN varchar2
     ) IS
-- --------------------------------------------------
   v_Count       NUMBER ;
   v_timestamp   VARCHAR2 (16) ;
   v_id   NUMBER ;
   JustModified  EXCEPTION ;
   JustDeleted   EXCEPTION ;
-- --------------------------------------------------
   BEGIN


      SELECT TAPT_ICPREC_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO v_id FROM DUAL ;

      INSERT INTO TAPT_IC_PREC_VENDOR 
        (
        Id
,VENDOR_NAME
,BUSINESS_ID
,MODIFIEDBY
,VENDOR_PROVINCE
,GST_HST_NUMBER
,VENDOR_SUITE
,PSF_SUPPLIER_ID
,TAX_EXEMPT
,DATEMODIFIED
,PERSON_ID
,VENDOR_STREET
,SK_PST_NUMBER
,QST_NUMBER
,CREATEDBY
,VENDOR_POSTALCODE
,DATECREATED
,PERSON_EMAIL
,VENDOR_CITY)
      VALUES 
        (v_id
,i_VENDOR_NAME 
,i_BUSINESS_ID 
,i_MODIFIEDBY 
,i_VENDOR_PROVINCE 
,i_GST_HST_NUMBER 
,i_VENDOR_SUITE 
,i_PSF_SUPPLIER_ID
,i_TAX_EXEMPT
,i_DATEMODIFIED
,i_PERSON_ID
,i_VENDOR_STREET
,i_SK_PST_NUMBER
,i_QST_NUMBER
,i_CREATEDBY
,i_VENDOR_POSTALCODE
,i_DATECREATED
,i_PERSON_EMAIL
,i_VENDOR_CITY) ;

         i_ID := v_id ; 

   EXCEPTION
       WHEN OTHERS THEN
          RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20303, SQLERRM (SQLCODE)) ;

   END ;
-- --------------------------------------------------
   

END TAPK_ICPREC_DATA;
```

Hope it helps to understand the issue.

Exception :
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TAPP_MAIN_INSERT'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

I tried some articles from oracle community as below

https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4502254/wrong-number-or-types-of-arguments-in-call-to-insert-row-how-i-can-resolve-this-error

It seems like Its due to wrong data type in call or spelling mistake , but I have crossed checked all the parameters.

Comment: What does `_unitOfWork.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync` do with what you've passed into it - does that add the appropriate number of bind variable placeholders to the actual procedure call? Maybe try to look at the actual statement that gets issued to the database and how the parameters are bound. You aren't supplying the parameters in the same order as the declarations, which might be relevant. You might also need to supply the argument names in upper-case, e.g. `"I_PERSON_ID"` instead of `"i_PERSON_ID"`.

Comment: Here _unitOfWork is an interface which have different signatures to run the sql script. We can pass plain SQL or define the stored procedure as i defined. This worked for me I have changed the  order as the declarations and changed in the upper case. Thank you so much. This is really helpful. Much appreciated

Comment: So what worked, changing the order/case, or changing the data types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are declaring the variables as `nvarchar` rather than `varchar`. That will cause this error for sure. The same thing might be true with `decimal`... you probably can't bind a `decimal` to a `number`, though I'm not 100% sure of that since decimal uses a number type under the covers. Make sure you use the exact matching datatypes in your Oracle client driver interface that corresponds with the datatypes of your procedure parameters.